# Case Validation rule - using custom metadata type

Tags: validation-rule, email2case, custom-metadata

I need to block certain email domains in order to create `Email2Case`. To meet this requirement, I have created

1. A custom metadata type (Case_Block_Email__mdt) and a text field called Email_Domains__c to hold comma separated email domains (e.g. @domain1.com, @domain2.com etc.)
2. A Case validation rule

> `CONTAINS(LOWER(SuppliedEmail), $CustomMetadata.Case_Block_Email__mdt.EmailToBlock.Email_Domains__c)`

[image]

**Now the issue is** : This validation is not working. When I debugged it, its giving me a strange error like "Support__EmailToBlock" Field does not exist. I am sure we are not using such field/created either.

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Is this custom metadata in a managed package, by chance? Did you check the **name** of the custom metadata record to make sure it matches?

Comment: @sfdcfox - I have created custom metadata manually. Yes I have checked the record name, its correct.

Comment: @sfdcfox but if I hardcode as `CONTAINS(LOWER(SuppliedEmail), "@domain1.com")` then its working well.

Comment: The problem has something to do with `Support__` being added to the value it's looking for, which is weird if this is not a managed package component.